# Converting to date and performing a count

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT a.UserID, a.SignUpDate, DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, a.SignUpDate, day) As DaysActive 
FROM (SELECT u.Userid, CAST(MIN(u.SessionLogin)AS DATE) AS SignUpDate
      FROM database.data_source.user_session_table as a)
```

The above code pulls the session login time from the user_session table performs a min function to collect their initial login, whilst converting it from a timestamp to a date format. DaysActive shows how many days since they have logged in.

What i am trying to do is find how many days they have logged into the application since their initial sign in.(Days Active)
SessionLogin field captures a timestamp each time they login, i am trying to convert that to a date, whilst also adding it to the above table as a count.

**Current Output**

```
UserID  | SignUpDate| DaysActive | 
--------+-----------+-------------
001     |2017-12-04 | 35         |
002     |2017-12-08 | 31         |
003     |2017-12-05 | 34         |
```

**user_session_table**

```
UserID  |SessionLogin         | 
--------+---------------------|
001     |2017-12-04 01:37:49  | 
001     |2017-12-08 05:47:04  | 
001     |2017-12-05 04:40:00  | 
002     |2017-12-08 12:25:39  | 
002     |2017-12-09 01:37:49  | 
003     |2017-12-05 05:47:04  | 
003     |2017-12-05 08:40:00  |
```

**Desired Output**

```
UserID  | SignUpDate | DaysActive| DaysEngaged
--------+-----------+------------+-----------
001     |2017-12-04 | 35         |3
002     |2017-12-08 | 31         |2
003     |2017-12-05 | 34         |1
```

**Code: MSSQL / Bigquery**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know about big query but for SQL Server you could do it like this.

```
select S.UserID,
       min(cast(S.SessionLogin as date)) as SignUpDate,
       datediff(day, min(cast(S.SessionLogin as date)), getdate()) as DaysActive,
       count(distinct cast(S.SessionLogin as date)) as DaysActive
from dbo.SessionLogin as S
group by S.UserID;
```